# What value does $\prod_{n=0}^\infty 1+{1\over x^n}$ converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, products, infinite-product

I would like to find out the exact value (if it can be written down and generalized) for the formula in the title for any x. I have got aproximate values, but **I would apreciate an exact value of a special case as well**.

I thought about the geometric series and asked myself if there was something for an infinite product as well. After some time I discovered: $$\prod_{n=0}^\infty 1+{1\over x^{2^n} } = {x \over x-1}$$
I found that out by looking at what I had to multiply ${x-1 \over x}$ with to get ${x^2-1 \over x^2}$. With $1+{1\over x^{2^n} } = {x^{2^n}+1 \over x^{2^n}}$ you always use the difference of two squares and it triggers something like a „chain reaction“.
Anyway, I tried to find out about:
$$\prod_{n=0}^\infty 1+{1\over x^n}$$
I checked with a computer and for values of x bigger than 1 or smaller than -1 it seems to converge. I also plotted the values and they looked similar to ${1\over 1-x}$ but without the part from -1 to 1. 
After some time I tried to expand it term by term and this pattern emerged:
$$\prod_{n=0}^\infty 1+{1\over x^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n) {1\over x^n}$$
a(n) here is sequence A122797 in the OEIS. I still don‘t know what this converges to.

I couldn‘t find anything about this on the internet. The only infinite products I could find where with n to some constant power.

I apreciate your help. Even for special cases, like for $x = 2$. Because I don‘t know any exact value of any case. Thanks!

Comment: @mathmaniac. Your formula is wrong. Try evaluating it at $x=1$, you get $2^{k+1}$ vs $k(k+1)$.

Comment: The formula is $$ \prod_{n=0}^N\left(1+\frac{1}{x^n}\right)=\sum_{I\subset[\![1,N]\!]}\prod_{i\in I}\frac{1}{x^i}=\sum_{I\subset[\![1,N]\!]}\frac{1}{x^{\sum_{i\in I}i}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N(N+1)}{2}}\frac{p(n)}{x^n} $$ where $p(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$. This leads to the already known formula $$ \prod_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^n}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{p(n)}{x^n} $$

Comment: Now that I tried to prove it using induction I also saw that it didn‘t work out. @math maniac Sorry...

Comment: @Tuvasbien Thanks!

Comment: @Tuvasbien Had to parse your formula a bit before it clicked so I'd like to add some clarification to some parts. Since the sum is over subsets of [1,N] all the i-numbers in the sums are distinct so it would be useful to specify that we are dealing with partitions into *distinct parts* so using the notation q(n) would be a little clearer. Also since the sum starts at n = 0 we end up with an additional factor of 2 independent of the partition argument $\sum 2 q(n) x^{-n}$. q(n) is corresponds to A000009 while I usually use p(n) for A000041